# How to prove it by means of a combinatorial argument?(A combinatorial exercise)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that $\binom{n}{\smash{0}}^2+\binom{n}{1}^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}^2=\binom{\smash{2}n}{n}$ using a counting argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111508/proof-that-binomn-smash02-binomn12-cdots-binomnn2-binom)

It is an exercise in a book on discrete mathematics.It is like this.

Give a combinatorial argument to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}C\left ( n,k \right)^{2}=C\left ( 2n,n \right )$.

I don't know how to begin with it.It's hard for me to construct such a set,or the context.I learned it by myself and no one around can help me whit my answer.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/91457) for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the right hand side of the equality. What does it tell you? Translated to english the RHS is "the number of n-subsets of a 2n-set" (where by n-set I mean a set of cardinality n). Now consider the $2n$-set. Split it up in two sets of equal size $n$. You can pick a n-set by choosing $n$ elements from one of the sets and zero from the other, or choosing $n-1$ elements from one of the n-sets and $1$ element from the other and so on. I.e. $$C(2n,n)=\sum{C(n,k)C(n,n-k)=\sum{C(n,k)^2}}$$ The last equality follows since the number of ways of choosing $k$ elements from a $n$ set is the same number of ways as choosing those $n-k$ elements that shall not belong to a $k$-subset.

Comment: Yes,at first I just can't catch that C(n,k)2 is just C(n,k)C(n,n−k).And I was stuck in it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_identity), as recommended by t.b.:
$$
    {m+n \choose r}=\sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k},\qquad m,n,r\in\mathbb{N}_0, 
$$
and set $m=n$, $r=n$ and use ${n \choose n-k}={n \choose k}$ to get:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}^2=    {2n \choose n}$$